# Создать массив данных

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста!

У меня есть список:

```
3. 1c4339449fbac9498fe422f4f5f1a5e4 - 3000
4. 3c7505a408e7c6d8c1e546ef2554bd86 - 3151    
5. 4dac49f4d9ac0155c1a8941d67a064a0 - 2861    
6. 673e67b0cae89166c3050adb6433ff7e - 3035    
7. 85ae1ea5e2b82ed9f92fbdb21c30b63e - 3197
8. 9fc3128ff599b7a72682d0ad3f970e22 - 2767
9. a2442322c09760cd9685f659a0178709 - 3555
10. c18f517310ccd9c3824cd6787dbf8475 - 3213
11. d74f444905710381aeaf30c6d06410c9 - 2890
12. ea1f622e7fcb6db49ac80f920409bb44 - 3179
```

Это код который его генерирует:

```
$path = 'storage';
$beforeDir = scandir('storage');
for ($i = 3; $i < count($beforeDir); $i++){
            $f_info = stat("storage/$beforeDir[$i]");
            $today = time();
            $lastDay = date($f_info[mtime]);
            $countDay = $today - $lastDay;
            echo "<span style='text-align: left; margin-left: 50px; color: green;'>$i. <i>$beforeDir[$i]</i></span> - $countDay"."<br />";
            $f_info = stat("storage/$beforeDir[$i]"); 
            //echo "Время последнего изменения файла: ".date("d M Y H:i:s" ,$f_info[mtime]) ."\n";
        }
```

В том списке имена файлов, ну как понятно из скрипта после имени я получил некое время, точнее кусочек, как мне теперь пройтись по списку и удалить файл с максимальным значением?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Получаем список всех файлов
$files = glob( './test/*.*' );
//сортируем
array_multisort(
array_map( 'filemtime', $files ),
SORT_NUMERIC,
SORT_DESC,
$files
);

echo $files[0]; // самый старый файл
```

Comment: Красивое решение!

Comment: Друг,огромное спасибо :), только у меня сортировка в обратном порядке, выводит наоборот самый свежий файл.

Comment: Все, разобрался :) Изменил SORT_DESC на SORT_ASC.
Гениальное решение! Жаль наградить не могу, зелен и молод я пока :( Просто большое человеческое спасибо!